# common-validator sbt dependency for scala 2.12.1

Tags: scala, sbt

My sbt file looks as follows

```
organization := "scala"
name := "MyProject"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.20.0"
libraryDependencies += "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "3.6"
libraryDependencies += "commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.6.0"
```

When I run `sbt compile` I get this

```
sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-validator#commons-validator;1.6.0: not found
```

However when I change scala version to 2.11.7, sbt compiles fine. What am I missing? How can I make it work for 2.12.1?

Comment: It's 1.6, not 1.6.0. Scala version doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mvnrepo (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator)

use `libraryDependencies += "commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.6"`